# RedirectMatch 301 multiple sub folders

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, redirect

How can I use RedirectMatch 301 to make `/2016/03/07/bla-bla` go to `/folder/bla-bla`
I need to redirect many month year folders in WordPress because I changed the URL naming after many posts were created, but need to keep the same ending path.

Comment: This pattern should work [`.+(?=bla-bla)`](https://regex101.com/r/pmt9MT/1)

Comment: How do I incorporate  `.+(?=bla-bla)` into
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/2016/03/07/bla-bla /folder/bla-bla` so I can just copy and paste into .HTACCESS file? Also `/bla/bla` needs to change so the first 3 subdirectories will be numbers but then the final page will be different pages. Something like this `RedirectMatch 301 ^/2016/03/07/(.*)$ /folder/$1` works for the page being able to change but I don't know how to make it so it will redirect any sub directories also.

Comment: I tried this `RedirectMatch 301 ^/20(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /folder/$4` but couldn't get it to work

Comment: @emsimpson92 can you help explain your response?